# center image in navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have added an image to my navbar in bootstrap but it is totally out of line. I want it to be centered to the left, what am i doing wrong?

The **HTML** code is :

```
<nav class = 'navbar navbar-default'>
  <div class = 'navbar-header'>
    <button type = 'button' class = 'navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle = 'collapse' data-target = '#example-navbar-collapse'>
      <span class = 'sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
      <span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
      <span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
    <a class = 'navbar-brand' href = '#'><img class='img-responsive2'       
      src='http://www.biophysics.org/portals/57/Images/newstar.png'></a>
  </div>
  <div class = 'collapse navbar-collapse' id = 'example-navbar-collapse'>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>About</a></li>
    </ul>  
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Get bids</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Register company</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Help</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
      <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and my **CSS** is :

```
.navbar-default {   
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #00a3fe;
    font-size: 14pt;font-weight: 400;}


.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #49bdfe;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-toggle, .icon-bar {
    border:1px solid white;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Thankyou for any help in advance.

Comment: could you give us a screen shot or upload `images/logo-new.png` here we can't figure your issue

Comment: its on cheekytransport.co.uk/images/logo-new.jpg

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 1):

By Adding those lines in css , it ixes the probleme :

```
//added css
.navbar-brand {
  padding:0 !important;
}


.img-responsive2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

here is a [BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/oWX7haRD27)

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.navbar-default {   
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #00a3fe !important;
    font-size: 14pt;font-weight: 400;
}


.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #49bdfe;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-toggle, .icon-bar {
    border:1px solid white;
    background-color:white;
}

//added css
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 ;
}


.img-responsive2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class = 'navbar navbar-default'>
  <div class = 'navbar-header'>
    <button type = 'button' class = 'navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle = 'collapse' data-target = '#example-navbar-collapse'>
      <span class = 'sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
      <span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
      <span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
    <a class ='navbar-brand'  style='padding:0 !important' href = '#'><img class='img-responsive2'       
      src='http://cheekytransport.co.uk/images/logo-new.png'></a>
  </div>
  <div class = 'collapse navbar-collapse' id = 'example-navbar-collapse'>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>About</a></li>
    </ul>  
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Get bids</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Register company</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Help</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='non-active'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
      <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks to comments i have it sorted it. It was just hight px. Its on cheekytransport.co.uk/23.php if you want to see it. Works anf fits good on all browsers without resizing

Answer (score 0):

set width and height for image like this

```
.img-responsive2 
    {
    width: auto;
    height: 35px;
    }
```

Comment: Yes good for changing size but its still half way down the top? I want it in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height of the image like this

```
.img-responsive2 {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Very simple example http://bootsbin.com/bin/view/44/

Comment: Hi, it works good with your example but when i change the image source and size it seems to go down rather than in the middle?

src='http://www.cheekytransport.co.uk/images/logo-new.png' height='50'>

Comment: And another annoying thing is when you mouse over the left links, the background turns light blue but doesnt fill the whole dark blue background, where as the search on the right does? Wierd

Comment: If i add this to the css

 .navbar-default {   
     height:66px;}

and set the image size to 40 it is actually in the middle but the rest of the menu is nearer the top?

Comment: You need to remove top and bottom padding from navbar. I have updated the code http://bootsbin.com/bin/view/44/

Comment: If you change the navbar height, you also have to change the navabr link padding.